# Не отображается файл

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Имеется код в котором введенное значение кладется в файл it's password.txt в директории C:\Windows\Sustem32\config. Программа работает отлично, файл создается, пароль сохраняется, но файл в директории я не вижу. Перепробвал уже все: в настройках проводника ставил "показывать системные файлы", снимал галку со "скрывать системные файлы". Ничего не помогает. Моя программа говорит мне о том, что файл есть и хэш в нем лежит. в видео это видно четко и ясно.
https://youtu.be/vxlo6aSFB5k

Comment: У вас, похоже, проблема с путями. В видео вы указываете путь к файлу как `c:\\Windows...`, а подразумеваете и здесь в вопросе пишете `C:\Windows...`

Comment: @Bulson Тоже так подумал но разницы нет что так, что так отправляю еще одно видео, где вожу путь по-другому.    https://youtu.be/8rQgw_L5WYI

Comment: @МаксимДонец код к вопросу приложите

Comment: @Lolidze честно говоря, я немного стесняюсь. Он совсем некрасивый.

Comment: @Lolidze Тут достаточно одной строки - `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Windows...", "Hello!");` и проверить далее есть файл в этой именно директории, или нет. Я проверил и действительно, файла нет, но если вывести все файлы директории через код - есть только те, что были созданы программно. Вообще, это очень специфическая директория и мне бы тоже хотелось узнать, в чем же ее особенность.

Comment: `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Comment: Это виртуализация системного каталога с вами шутит. Специально сделано против программ, которые не прочь хранить свои данные не там, где нужно — например, в системном каталоге. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681

Comment: Пишите свои данные туда, куда положено. Например, в `%APPDATA%\<имя вашей программы>`

Comment: @VladD прикольно, не знал. Почему бы не ответом?

Comment: @tym32167: Написал.

Comment: @VladD молодец :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что Windows не разрешает приложению с правами пользователя писать в системный каталог.

Раньше, во времена Windows 95, любое приложение имело право писать куда угодно, и часто могло обрушить систему, переписав важные настройки или подменив системную библиотеку. Если просто отобрать у приложений права на системный каталог, то старые программы, написанные без учёта безопасности системы, будут просто валиться. Для обеспечения обратной совместимости для таких программ системой проводится виртуализация системного каталога и реестра: если программа пишет в запрещённое место, система считает, что автор программы не читал документацию, и притворяется, что всё в порядке. При этом система на деле складывает файлы в `%LOCAL­APP­DATA%\Virtual­Store`, а ключи реестра — в `HKCU\Software\Classes\Virtual­Store`.

При этом приложению при чтении подставляются значения, как будто бы оно смогло записать туда, куда нельзя. Другие приложения при этом, понятно, ничего не увидят.

Если вы хотите писать куда-то данные, правильное место для них — каталог `%APPDATA%\<имя вашего приложения>\`. Не надейтесь на виртуализацию: рано или поздно Майкрософт перестанет поддерживать совместимость с багами Windows 95, и код начнёт просто падать.

Литература:

- [I saved some files into the Program Files directory, and now they’re gone! — *The Old New Thing*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681)
- [Inside Windows Vista User Account Control — *Mark Russinovich*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.uac.aspx)
- [How User Account Control works — *Microsoft Docs*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works#virtualization).