# Как прочитать эти файлы в планировщике задач

Tags: c#, windows, планировщик-задач

Мне нужно  вытащить из планировщика задач все файлы, которые им запускаются при старте системы, почитал много методов, но везде используются сторонние библиотеки не входящие в стандартную поставку студии, нашел где лежат сами файлы планировщика, это по виду обычные xml, но без расширения.
c:\Windows\System32\Tasks\  это для win7, вопрос как мне их увидеть программно.
Вот стандартно  делаю. К сожалению другого пути как вытащить запускаемые при старте системы из планировщика не нашел.

```
string path = @"c:\Windows\System32\Tasks\ ";

// смотрим есть ли файлы с таким расширением
string[] filesname = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*");

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",filesname));
```

Comment: Распарсить XML просто: можно использовать встроенный `XDocument`, к примеру. Но вот по поводу формата и смысла содержимого скорее всего вам никто ничего не подскажет, т. к. эти файлы не предназначены для обработки внешними утилитами.

Comment: @VladD это я понимаю, только тогда как мне добраться до задач в планировщике минуя сторонние библиотеки. WMI тоже не показывает

Comment: Ну, вы можете помедитировать на формат этих файлов и попробовать угадать, что в них что означает. С хорошей долей вероятности там просто набор сериализированных объектов.

Comment: @VladD дак формата все равно нет, я же даже не могу подхватить его чем то

Comment: а из-за чего такая ненависть к сторонним библиотекам?

Comment: @Monomax условия задачи такие, под сторонними библиотеками я имею ввиду те библиотеки,которых нет в стандартной поставке студии

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch: То есть как это нету? Ну загляните в файл глазами, вы не увидите разные сами логическую структуру?

Comment: @VladD то , что там xml голимый)), вопрос,как мне взять файл этот или файлы, если я их программно не вижу.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch во-первых, система не обязательно устанавливается на диск _C:_, во-вторых, если "программно не видите", значит у программы нет нужных прав.

Comment: @gregzakharov  я даже расширение не вижу в Тотал-командере

Comment: А тут случаем не [виртуализация системного каталога](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811417/Не-отображается-файл)?

Comment: А зачем вам расширение? Открывайте без расширения и читайте.

Comment: А не открывает небось потому, что у нас прав на чтение нету. Вы исключения ловите?

Comment: @VladD а можно пример,как взять файл без расширения?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch: `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*");`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы парсить XML, лучше воспользоваться [библиотекой COM-объектов планировщика задач](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/enumerating-tasks-and-displaying-task-information). Она должна быть в составе ОС по крайней мере начиная с Windows 7.

```
//Reference: COM -> Task scheduler 1.1 type library
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using TaskScheduler;

...       

static void PrintFolder(ITaskFolder folder) //метод для рекурсивного обхода каталогов
{
    IRegisteredTaskCollection coll = null;
    ITaskDefinition def = null;
    ITaskFolderCollection folders = null;
    IExecAction exec = null;

    try
    {
        coll = folder.GetTasks(0); //найдем задачи в каталоге

        foreach (IRegisteredTask item in coll)
        {
            if (def != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(def); def = null; }
            if (exec != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exec); exec = null; }

            def = item.Definition;
            bool autostart = false;

            foreach (ITrigger trig in def.Triggers)
            {
                //нас интересуют только задачи, запускающиеся при включении или входе пользователя
                if (trig.Type == _TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_BOOT ||
                    trig.Type == _TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON)
                {
                    autostart = true; break;
                }
            }

            if (autostart)
            {
                //выведем информацию о задаче
                Console.Write( item.Name + " ");
                foreach (IAction act in def.Actions)
                {
                    if (act.Type != _TASK_ACTION_TYPE.TASK_ACTION_EXEC)
                    {
                        Console.Write( "(" + act.Type.ToString() + ")");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exec = (IExecAction)act;
                        //выведем командную строку, запускаемую задачей
                        Console.Write( "(" + exec.Path + " " + exec.Arguments + ")");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        //обходим подкаталоги текущего каталога
        folders = folder.GetFolders(0);
        foreach (ITaskFolder item in folders)
        {
            PrintFolder(item);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (coll != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(coll);
        if (def != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(def);
        if (folders != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folders);
        if (exec != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exec);
    }
}

public static void PrintTasks() 
{
    TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler ts = null;
    ITaskService its = null;
    ITaskFolder folder = null;

    try
    {
        ts = new TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler();
        its = (ITaskService)ts;

        //подключаемся к локальной машине
        its.Connect();

        //получаем корневой каталог задач
        folder = its.GetFolder("\\");                

        //рекурсивно выводим задачи
        PrintFolder(folder);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (folder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
        if (its != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(its);
        if (ts != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо. это то ,что нужно